# Group By a Column and Sum contents of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe `merged_df_energy`:

```
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 | ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3 | ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5 | class_energy |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 63.333333              | 63.333333              | 63.333333              | low          |
| 0                      | 0                      | 0                      | high         |
| 45.67                  | 0                      | 55.94                  | high         |
| 0                      | 0                      | 23.99                  | low          |
| 0                      | 20                     | 23.99                  | medium       |
+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

I would like to create for each `ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_Fx` (`ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1`, `ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3` and `ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5`) a dataframe which contains these columns: `class_energy` and `sum_time`

For example for the dataframe corresponding to `ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1`:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|  class_energy   | sum_time  |
+-----------------+-----------+
| low             | 63.333333 |
| medium          | 0         |
| high            | 45.67     |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

I thing to do I should use the group by like this:

```
data.groupby(by=['class_energy'])['sum_time'].sum()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add all columns to `[]` for aggregating:

```
print (df.groupby(by=['class_energy'])['ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1', 'ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5'].sum())
              ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  \
class_energy                                                   
high                       45.670000                0.000000   
low                        63.333333               63.333333   
medium                      0.000000               20.000000   

              ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5  
class_energy                          
high                       55.940000  
low                        87.323333  
medium                     23.990000
```

You can use also parameter `as_index=False`:

```
print (df.groupby(by=['class_energy'], as_index=False)['ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1', 'ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3','ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5'].sum())
  class_energy  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  \
0         high               45.670000                0.000000   
1          low               63.333333               63.333333   
2       medium                0.000000               20.000000   

   ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5  
0               55.940000  
1               87.323333  
2               23.990000
```

If need aggregate only first `3` columns:

```
print (df.groupby(by=['class_energy'], as_index=False)[df.columns[:3]].sum())
  class_energy  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  \
0         high               45.670000                0.000000   
1          low               63.333333               63.333333   
2       medium                0.000000               20.000000   

   ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5  
0               55.940000  
1               87.323333  
2               23.990000
```

...or all columns without last:

```
print (df.groupby(by=['class_energy'], as_index=False)[df.columns[:-1]].sum())
  class_energy  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  \
0         high               45.670000                0.000000   
1          low               63.333333               63.333333   
2       medium                0.000000               20.000000   

   ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5  
0               55.940000  
1               87.323333  
2               23.990000
```

Comment: Thank you for upvoting. Can I edit your question to be more readible?